# How to check for no image and continue process without terminating

Tags: php

Here is my Script for Uploading...

```
<?php
session_start();
//Create Post
include_once '../../config/database_connection.php';
include_once '../module/selectUser.php';
   if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: ../../login404");
}
//Grab Image Data
$image_fieldname = "uploadphoto";

//Data Request
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$view = $_REQUEST['view'];

//Function definations
function MakeUrls($status)
{
    $find=array('`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si','`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si');
    $replace=array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>','<a href="'. BASE_URL .'php/module/recordLink.php?link=$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$status);
}
//Function testing
$status = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "<br>", $_REQUEST['status']);
//Make Url clickable
$status=MakeUrls($status);
$status=preg_replace('/#(\\w+)/','<a href="'. BASE_URL .'php/hash/index?hash=$1">$0</a>',$status);
//Check for Mentions
$status=preg_replace('/(@\w+)/','<a href="'. BASE_URL .'php/mention?username=$1">$0</a>',$status);

//Reg ErrorException
$status = str_replace('<script>', '',$status);
$status = str_replace('</script>', '',$status);
$status = str_replace('<p>', '',$status);
$status = str_replace('</p>', '',$status);
$status = str_replace('<style>', '',$status);
$status = str_replace('</style>', '',$status);
$likes = 0;


// Potential PHP upload errors
$php_errors = array(1 => 'Maximum file size in php.ini exceeded',
        2 => 'Maximum file size in HTML form exceeded',
        3 => 'Only part of the file was uploaded',
        4 => 'No file was selected to upload.');

// Make sure we didn't have an error uploading the image
($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['error'] == 0)
or handle_error("the server couldn't upload the image you selected.",
$php_errors[$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['error']]);

// Is this file the result of a valid upload?
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'])
or handle_error("you were trying to do something naughty. Shame on you!",
"Uploaded request: file named " .
"'{$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']}'");

// Is this actually an image?
@getimagesize($_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name'])
or handle_error("you selected a file for your picture " .
"that isn't an image.",
"{$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['tmp_name']} " .
"isn't a valid image file.");

// Name the file uniquely
$now = time();
while (file_exists($upload_filename = $upload_dir . $now .
'-' .
$_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'])) {
$now++;
}

// Insert the image into the images table
$image = $_FILES[$image_fieldname];
$image_filename = "Circlepanda-image" . $image['name'];
$image_info = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']);
$image_mime_type = $image_info['mime'];
$image_size = $image['size'];
$image_data = file_get_contents($image['tmp_name']);

//Initial Image Upload Commented Out
$insert_image_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO post_img " .
"(filename, mime_type, file_size, image_data, user_id) " .
"VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s');",
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $image_filename),
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $image_mime_type),
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $image_size),
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $image_data),
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $user_id));
mysqli_query($conn, $insert_image_sql)
or handle_error("Could'nt upload image to our database"
, mysql_error($conn));


$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO user_post (fullname, view, status, date, likes, user_id, profile_pic_id, image_id) " .
          "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d); ",
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fullname),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $view),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $status),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $date),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $likes),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $user_id),
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $profile_pic_id),
            mysqli_insert_id($conn));

// Insert the Post into the database
if (mysqli_query($conn, $insert_sql)) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Your status was successfully updated";
    header("Location: "  . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else {
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "Unsuccessful status update";
    header("Location: "  . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
}
?>
```

No doubt it works fine, but in a situation where no Image is uploaded it send me to an error page. But what i really want is to, skip image upload script and upload just users status. I don't know how to make this work. :(

Comment: What version of PHP do you have?  Since php 5.3.0 you can use goto http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php to skip ahead (with some restriction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer from somewhere around stack overflow... Thanks guys for helping... Answer below... Once again thanks.

```
if ($_FILES['cover_image']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 0) {
   #cover_image is empty (and not an error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value as **null** for your `image` column in the database and then check if you have an `image` for **example**:

```
if ( you have a image) {
  // render sql query with image
} else {
  // if you don't have render a query without image
}
then excute your query
```

Comment: Please notice I am requesting the image differently, 
$image_fieldname = "uploadphoto";
And if i use an if or else statement, It'll always be true cause php would be seeing it as a string...
So please, i need something better than if () {} else {}. Thanks!